# Replacing a comma seperate value in table with another in select query (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, table A has ID column whose values are comma separated, each of those ID value has a representation in table B.

```
   Table A
+-----------------+
| Name      | ID   |
+------------------
| A1        | 1,2,3|
| A2        | 2    |
| A3        | 3,2  |
+------------------

   Table B
+-------------------+
| ID        | Value |
+-------------------+
| 1        | Apple  |
| 2        | Orange |
| 3        | Mango  |
+-------------------+
```

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do a select where the result would as below,

```
  Name, Value
  A1    Apple, Orange, Mango
  A2    Orange
  A3    Mango, Orange

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first "normalize" `table_a` into a new table using the following:

```
select name, regexp_split_to_table(id, ',')  id
from table_a;
```

The result of this can be joined to `table_b` and the result of the join then needs to be grouped in order to get the comma separated list of the names:

```
select a.name, string_agg(b.value, ',')
from (
  select name, regexp_split_to_table(id, ',')  id
  from table_a
) a
  JOIN table_b b on b.id = a.id
group by a.name;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/77fdf/1

Comment: thanks for the response, I am normalizing as suggested and using a join to group it back.

Answer (score 0):

There are two regex related functions that can be useful:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

- regexp_split_to_table()
- regexp_split_to_array()

Code below is untested, but you'd use something like it to match A and B:

```
select name, value
from A
join B on B.id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(A.id, E'\\s*,\\s*', 'g')::int[]))
```

You can then use array_agg(value), grouping by name, and format using array_to_string().

Two notes, though:

1. It won't be as efficient as normalizing things.
2. The formatting itself ought to be done further down, in your views.